# Can anyone explain me, how this struct initalization is actually working?

Tags: c, struct, coding-style, initialization

```
struct audio_policy_service_ops {

audio_io_handle_t (*open_duplicate_output)(void *service,audio_io_handle_t output1,  
     int (*close_output)(void *service, audio_io_handle_t output);audio_io_handle_t output2);
     int (*suspend_output)(void *service, audio_io_handle_t output);
     int (*restore_output)(void *service, audio_io_handle_t output);
};
```

Now they're being initialized as shown below:

```
struct audio_policy_service_ops aps_ops = {
    open_duplicate_output : aps_open_dup_output,
    close_output          : aps_close_output,
    suspend_output        : aps_suspend_output,
    restore_output        : aps_restore_output,
};
```

Comment: You won't find such a construct in C++. It only exists in C.

Comment: This code is used in a c++ file.
But, yes struct "audio_io_handle_t " is declared in a c file.

Comment: This syntax has been obsolete since GCC 2.5. The standard syntax is `.memberName = value`.

Comment: In that case, it's a non-standard extension, presumably with the same meaning as C's designators.

Comment: According to [GCC's page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html), this is not implemented in C++.

Comment: @MikeSeymour it's an extension to C and it's called the "old-style GNU struct initialization".

Comment: This code is part of one android native library.

If its non-standard C++ extension. Could you please provide me its non-standard specification. Any link?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant. Thanks so much. I just gone through the comment and read the whole link. I got my answer

Comment: it's gnu89, deprecated in favor of C99's named struct initialization

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a non-standard, GCC-specific initialization syntax for structures. It's colloquially called the "old-style GNU struct init syntax". Its standard equivalent is something like

```
struct Foo bar = { .name1 = value1, .name2 = value2 };
```

You can read more about it [in the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is a GCC-ism. When initializing a structure, one could prefix the initialisation values with the name of the structure field. This allows the initialisers to follow a random order and makes it more clear what field a given values goes to.